# Matlab train svm regressor using LIBVM with a sparse matrix of text

Tags: matlab, regression, sparse-matrix, libsvm

I am conducting a Bag Of Words analysis where I have a sparse matrix of 80x60452, where 1:80 represent the number of days for the text collected on each day. This matrix represents a collection of tweets on a particular day. The experiment is part of a univariate time series prediction and im not to sure how to implement this.

I am using the Text Matrix Generator (TMG) to construct this sparse matrix which will be used agains a response column vector of price observations(80x1).

I will use a the first 70 observations to train the SVM regressor to predict future price instances given a test data set of the remaining instances.

For example:

```
T = (length(priceData)-10);

trainBoW = BoW(1:T,1:end);
testBoW = BoW(T+1:end,1:end);

trainPrice = pData(1:T);
testPrice = pData(T+1:end);

model = svmtrain(trainBoW, trainPrice,'-c 1 -g 0.07 -b 1');
```

Running this code throws the error:
Error using svmtrain (line 274)
SVMTRAIN only supports classification into two groups. GROUP contains 62 groups.

How can I train a SVM regression model using libsvm to predict future price instances ?

Comment: It  looks like you accidentally call the function `svmtrain` from Matlab's Statistics Toolbox, not from libsvm. Make sure you have properly installed libsvm including the Matlab interface, and the installation directory is on the path before the Statistics Toolbox.

Comment: I have correctly installed the libsvm package and have added the folder to my matlab path. How do I ensure I call the correct function?

Comment: Adam, as I said: make sure the libsvm installation directory is on the path *before* the Statistics Toolbox, meaning higher up (lower index) in the path list. The easiest way to look at and edit the path is `pathtool`. Just issuing another `addpath(path-to-libsvm)` immediately before you run your code should resolve the issue, too. Or you could remove the Statistics Toolbox entries from your path, if you don't need them otherwise (everything that contains `toolbox/stats`).

Comment: It worked perfectly. Much appreciated, however the following error is thrown when calling the svmtrain from the libsvm directory.... Error: label vector should not be in sparse format. The model returns as an empty matrix for some reason.

Comment: I guess that means libsvm does not support a sparse matrix as input. Use `full`.